# Strange double frame for password text box in Wix UI

Tags: user-interface, wix, windows-installer, msi-gui

When I use in my custom dialog Control Edit with attribute password set to "yes"

```
<Control Id="TextBoxPass" Type="Edit" Password="yes" Property="SQLPASSWORD">
```

the text box have double frame in Windows Server 2012.In other versions of Windows Server (2008, 2008R2, 2003) it looks like normal text box. How can I change this behavior? (I mean delete double frame)

[image: double frame for password textbox in 2012]

Comment: Also seen here: http://sourceforge.net/p/wix/mailman/message/32101693/

Comment: Sounds like a bug, but out of curiosity; if you hit tab several times, does it show a tab-order? Btw, nicely presented question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Quick answer**: AFAIK, you can't change this behavior.

**Long answer**: If you run Microsoft Spy++ and search for both controls you will see the class for the regular edit is `RichEdit20W`, while for the password is `Edit`.

Then inspecting the Window Styles you will find the `WS_BORDER`. This is the culprit for the border. In WiX and in MSI there is no way to code the window styles of a control, so I assume there is no solution to this issue.

Additionally, some styles (like ES_PASSWORD) can be changed using Orca and editing the `Attributes` column in table `Control`. The solution would be to have both edits set as password and after the build you manually edit the `Attributes` setting of the non-password control to `196611`.

In case you want to automate this process, I think you can code an application using the MSI API to execute a query against the package and change the value.

Here is a real example:

[image: Two edit controls, one without the ES_PASSWORD style.]